# How to use Scala's Ordering#reverse with a TreeMap?

Tags: scala, dictionary, tree

Scala's `Ordering` trait has a method `reverse` which seems to be the "official" way to get a `TreeMap` which is sorted "the wrong" way.

The snippet of the trait looks like this:

```
trait Ordering[T] extends Comparator[T] with PartialOrdering[T] with Serializable {
  outer =>

  override def reverse: Ordering[T] = new Ordering[T]{
    override def reverse = outer
    def compare(x: T, y: T) = outer.compare(y, x)
  }
  /*snip*/
}
```

I thought it would work comparable to Java's `Collections.reverseOrder`, but `Ordering.reverse` doesn't work of course.

How can I use the reverse Ordering with a TreeMap, e. g.:

```
new TreeMap[Foo, Bar](/*???*/)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
new TreeMap[Foo, Bar]()(implicitly[Ordering[Foo]].reverse)
```

Assuming, of course, that `Ordering[Foo]` is implicitly available (such as `Ordering[Int]` or `Ordering[String]`). If you have it defined as `object X`, just pass `X.reverse` instead.

Note that the first set of parenthesis here must be empty -- it is only the second set of parenthesis that receive the implicit parameter in this particular case.

Comment: Apparently, if `Foo extends Ordered[Foo]`, then an `Ordering[Foo]` is implicitly available. Is that correct? And where does it come from?

Comment: @ChristopherSahnwaldt It is correct, it comes from object `Ordering`, iirc.

Answer (score 2):

```
new TreeMap[Foo,Bar]()(Ordering[Foo].reverse)
```

also works. Nice! Succinct and without `implicitly` magic.

What's really going on here, if I'm not mistaken:

- `Odering[Foo]` calls `Ordering.apply`, which has an implicit parameter (which is itself of type Ordering)
- the implicit def `Ordering.ordered` is found (I'm not sure why) for that parameter and creates a new `Ordering` object
- that `Ordering` object is passed to and returned by `Ordering.apply`
- `reverse` is called on that `Ordering` object and creates another new `Ordering` object

I'm mixing run-time and compile-time lingo here, but you'll catch my drift.

Answer (score 1):

`new TreeMap[Foo,Bar]()(Ordering.ordered[Foo].reverse)` should work if there is no object for `Ordering[Foo]`, as long as `Foo extends Ordered[Foo]` (or more generally `Foo extends Comparable[Foo]`).

Comment: I guess Daniel's solution does the same thing, mine just makes it explicit.